# How do I merge US counties consistently?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I am new to QGIS.

My project involves county-level data. The problem is that US counties keep changing! (See the US Historical Counties project: http://publications.newberry.org/ahcbp/)

Since my other data do not keep account of these changes, I plan to merge counties to create a single consistent geographic unit over time.

For example, if county A splits into county A and county B, then I simply treat county B as county A for the remainder of the time sample.

Are there any good ways to do this in QGIS, without arduously going through the attribute table?

Comment: In which format do you have the data about counties splitting/merging over time?

Comment: Ok but how is the temporal aspect modeled?

Comment: From the help file, "The Historical Counties master shapefile contains separate polygons for each unique county shape during the state's history. Due to the numerous changes that have occurred in county boundaries, the master shapefile includes many overlapping polygons. Each polygon includes field values specifying the start and end dates for that particular shape."

Comment: For an exemplary way to handle this problem, which occurs at all levels of administrative organization, study the US Census Bureau's [relationship files](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/relationship.html). A good place to start in the documentation might be with one of the ["Understanding ..." documents.](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/pdfs/rel/tractrelfile.pdf)

Comment: For me, the problem description is still too vague. Maybe you could add one specific example of what you need to solve.

Comment: My time period is 1882-2000. So, for example, suppose County A splits into Counties A and B. Then, County B gains land from County C. I want QGIS to create a polygon that merges all three counties into a single county.

Comment: How is the County split / merge modelled? That is, how can you tell a polygon (notionally County A) in one set of shapefiles relates (say the 1882 set) to two polygons (notionally Counties A and B), and not any other polygons, in the 1982 set? Do you have some attribute that relates them?